# Why CFileDialog::GetNextPathName doesn't work when the file path is long?

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc, path, cfiledialog

Using `CFileDialog` class, I select multiple files placed in a directory with a long path. It's OK when I select only one or two files; but when I select three files at the same time it returns only a part of the third file path. (Looks like it's limited to 512 characters possibly) How can I resolve this?

Comment: Does it have to do with Window's `MAX_PATH`?

Comment: It has to do with MFC using a buffer of size `_MAX_PATH` by default. It can be overriden.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MFC uses a default buffer of size `_MAX_PATH` and that's why you are seeing that behavior. Look at `dlgfile.cpp` for the implementation of `CFileDialog::CFileDialog` and you will see `m_ofn.lpstrFile` and `m_ofn.nMaxFile` being set.

You can specify a larger buffer if you want to. Before calling `DoModal` you can either access the `CFileDialog::m_pOFN` member to get a pointer to the `OPENFILENAME` that the `CFileDialog` will use and update it directly or call `CFileDialog::GetOFN` to get a reference to the structure and update that.

Either way you will find this helpful: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms646839(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: If you're going to go through the trouble of working around it, you might also want to consider using the [Common Item Dialogs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/bb776913.aspx) instead. The `GetOpenFileName` API was deprecated with the release of Vista, but is still supported for legacy applications.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your code looks something like this:

```
CFileDialog dialog(...);
dialog.DoModal();
```

---

Determine the maximum number of files that you wish to support, for example:

```
#define MAX_FILE_NAMES 256
```

---

Add this before calling `DoModal`:

```
CString data;
dialog.m_pOFN->nMaxFile = (MAX_FILE_NAMES*(MAX_PATH+1))+1;
dialog.m_pOFN->lpstrFile = data.GetBuffer((MAX_FILE_NAMES*(MAX_PATH+1))+1);
```

---

Add this after calling `DoModal`:

```
data.ReleaseBuffer();
```