# CFileDialog::GetNextPathName return a truncated path if it is too long

Tags: c++, mfc, cfiledialog

I'm using CFileDialog to open files, I allow multiple selection, when the user select multiple files I iterate over them using CFileDialog::GetNextPathName method, but if the file name is too large it returns it truncated i don't know why is that??

The files were generated with random names and the files were created successfully but when i tried to open them using the CFileDialog some of them were too long like

```
"dFR.45434$#%@#3$FDGH.reR'FGDF,jh'+=gh.fghj&^%$!()rthyfgf.gfdhdfAZXCNMNrtyuIUU;k][sdgf]fd(jk~-.ggfddFR.45434$#%@#3$FDGH.reR'FGDF,jh'+=gh.fghj&^%$!()rthyfgf.gfdhdfAZXCNMNrtyuIUU;k][sdgf]fd(jk~-.ggfddFR.45434$#%@#3$FDGH.reR'FGDF,jh'+=gh.fghj&^%$!()rthyfgf"
```

the CFileDialog::GetNextPathName method returns it with some lost characters from the end of it. I don't know what is the problem! I'm sure that the full path of the file has a length less than MAX_PATH

**Solution**

---

I thought that the buffer will contain a one by one fie name and calling get next will fill it with the next but i found that all the files paths are concatenated separated with ' ' or '\0' depending on some flags the following worked with me fine

```
CFileDialog fd;
UINT maxFiles = 50;
UINT buffSize = maxFiles*(MAX_PATH + 1) +1;
CString buffer;
fd.GetOFN().lpstrFile = buffer.GetBuffer(buffSize);
fd.GetOFN().nMaxFile = buffSize;

if(fd.DoModal() == IDOK)
{
    //get start position using GetStartPosition , iterate over files using GetNextPathName
}
buffer.ReleaseBuffer();
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14903639/2065121

Comment: @Roger Rowland: Thanks for that, I'll try to use that solution but I'm sure that the path is lower than MAX_PATH.