# CFileDialog with OFN_ALLOWMULTISELECT incorrect results for shortcuts

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc, cfiledialog

Can someone let me know what am I doing wrong here?

MFC project, I'm using [`CFileDialog`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cfiledialog-class?view=vs-2017) to let user pick multiple files, as such:

```
CFileDialog fd(TRUE, NULL, NULL,
    OFN_HIDEREADONLY | OFN_OVERWRITEPROMPT | OFN_EXPLORER | OFN_ALLOWMULTISELECT, 
    NULL, this);

if(fd.DoModal() == IDOK)
{
    //Multi-selection
    CString strPaths;
    POSITION fileNamesPosition = fd.GetStartPosition();

    while(fileNamesPosition != NULL)
    {
        if(!strPaths.IsEmpty())
            strPaths += L"\n";

        strPaths += fd.GetNextPathName(fileNamesPosition);
    }  

    AfxMessageBox(strPaths);
}
```

So if say, there're two shortcut files:

`shortcut_1.lnk` file that refers to: `"D:\Folder\Project_B\Release\Name of Project B.exe"`

and `shortcut_2.lnk` that refers to `"D:\Folder\Project_A\Release\Name of Project A.exe"`

If I pick both of them from the "File Open" dialog generated by the code above, my resulting `strPaths` becomes the following, which is incorrect:

```
D:\Folder\Project_A\Release\Name of Project A.exe
D:\Folder\Project_A\Release\Name of Project B.exe
```

The second path is wrong!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the `GetStartPosition()` and `GetNextPathName()` functions is a mess. For one, they use the old-style API [which depends on a correct return buffer size defined via `OPENFILENAME` struct](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14903496/7571258). MFC **does not** take care of this! As your question shows, it also has problems with links, even if the buffer size is big enough.

Save yourself a headache and use the [Vista+ API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-ifileopendialog), which is available through `CFileDialog::GetIFileOpenDialog()`.

Here is a working code sample:

```
CFileDialog fd( TRUE, NULL, NULL,
    OFN_HIDEREADONLY | OFN_OVERWRITEPROMPT | OFN_EXPLORER | OFN_ALLOWMULTISELECT,
    NULL, nullptr );

if (fd.DoModal() == IDOK)
{
    //Multi-selection
    CString strPaths;

    CComPtr<IFileOpenDialog> piod = fd.GetIFileOpenDialog();
    ASSERT( piod );

    CComPtr<IShellItemArray> pResults;
    if( SUCCEEDED( piod->GetResults( &pResults ) ) )
    {
        DWORD count = 0; pResults->GetCount( &count );
        for( DWORD i = 0; i < count; ++i )
        {
            CComPtr<IShellItem> pItem;
            if( SUCCEEDED( pResults->GetItemAt( i, &pItem ) ) )
            {
                CComHeapPtr<wchar_t> pPath;
                if( SUCCEEDED( pItem->GetDisplayName( SIGDN_FILESYSPATH, &pPath ) ) )
                {
                    if( !strPaths.IsEmpty() )
                        strPaths += L"\n";
                    strPaths += pPath;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    AfxMessageBox( strPaths );
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Some notes re. your code. 1) I'd use my originally provided code as a fallback if your `piod` is null. Otherwise it will crash on WinXP. 2) Small gripe. I'd use `DWORD i` in the `for` loop to match `count` type to prevent warnings. and 3) can I say that every inch of my body **absolutely loathes COM**! It is such an abomination. For instance, what am I suppose to do if any of those five COM functions fail?

Comment: @c00000fd 1) Make sure to also allocate a big enough return buffer for XP (I've added a link in the 1st paragraph), otherwise users will ge problems when selecting too many files. 2) Thanks, fixed. 3) You do what you do with any error, report it, log it, whatever is appropriate. Personally I would wrap the stuff in a single function that returns `std::vector<std::wstring>` and throws a `std::system_error` containing the `HRESULT` and the name of the function that failed. Should be very rare that these function fail, propably out-of-memory situations only.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the follow up. I was already pre-allocating [32767](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx) `wchar_t`'s for the old XP buffer in `fd.m_ofn.lpstrFile` and `fd.m_ofn.nMaxFile` variables. It's just that it didn't return correct results -- that was the issue. But I guess that bug will stay with XP, if someone is still using it.

Comment: @c00000fd Otherwise Remy has a possible workaround, that should also work under XP.

Comment: Yeah, I thought of using `OFN_NODEREFERENCELINKS` flag myself. It's not very sensible though for the software that I need it for to return a link itself instead of the file that it points to. As for trying to fix it for XP users, their number must be really dwindling now. That OS can't have a large user share these days, can it? When you write your software, what range of OSs do you cover?

Comment: @c00000fd Fortunately my employer doesn't support XP anymore. For private projects I would start with Windows 7 as oldest support OS.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a bug in `CFileDialog`.

Typically, the returned paths are a concatenation of the currently displayed directory path and the selected filenames.  In the case of a `lnk` file, perhaps `CFileDialog` is extracting just the target filename and concatenating it to the path of the parent folder of the `lnk` file, rather than just returning the full target path that is inside the `lnk` file.  Hard to say for sure without seeing the actual source code for `CFileDialog`.

To avoid this behavior, you can include the `OFN_NODEREFERENCELINKS` flag when invoking the dialog, so you get the full paths to the actual `lnk` files, and then you can manually resolve their targets using [`IShellLink`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/shell/links) after the dialog has been dismissed.